# Failed building wheel for Pillow while installing tkinterdesigner

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install tkdesigner and when I try to do that it gives me this error code:

```
      <string>:46: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 8.4.0 does not support Python 3.11 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have the newest version of PIP and
Ive tried multiple fixes from the internet, but nothing works
how do I get it to work?

Comment: I got it, it doesnt work when you install it from pip. You have to clone the repo from Github, then everything works.